# Check if Blazor app is WebAssembly or Server?

Tags: blazor

Started a project via cmd so not sure if it is a WebAssembly App och Server side app.

Anybody know how to check this in an easy way in Visual Studio/cmd?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can open the .csproj file and look at the first line.
Blazor Server App project is using Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" but Blazor WebAssembly App is using Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly".

Answer (score 13):

### Update (.net 5 and up)

The quickest way is to look in **Program.cs**

Blazor WebAssembly:

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
```

Blazor Server:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

also, the presence of any .cshtml files, mainly `Pages\_Host.cshtml`,  means it is a Blazor Server project.

#### Old answer

There are several points in the project you can easily check.

Look for the line `services.AddServerSideBlazor();` in ConfigureServices()

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it is a server side app as the AddServerSideBlazor is present.

Comment: Is there a way to identify based on the packages/dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

If three projects (.Client, .Server, .Shared) were created, this is a WebAssembly Blazor App hosted (on the server).

If a single project was created, it might be a WebAssembly Blazor stand alone App,
or a Blazor Server App. In that case you should look for the Startup class. If exists, that means that your project is a Blazor Server App, if not then it is a WebAssembly Blazor stand alone. This is basically how I often view the structure of my solution, by a quick scan.

Comment: Thanks, seems like it's a server side app then as I have a Startup class :)

Comment: To be clear, you _can_ have a Startup class in wasm app. It's just not in the standard templates.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know...  but this is not relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could check it by running the app in localhost and then checking the initiator in network traffic when the app launches.